# TensorFlow, the output of AlexNet are all zero, after training several steps, and sometime the output is all the same in each dimension

Tags: tensorflow, output

[here is the output of AlexNet, I mean it's the output of the third full-connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhxPr.png)

I don't know why all the output is zero. And I try to reduce the layer, while cutting the last two layer, the output is all the same in each dimension, after training several steps. Any idea will be appreciated.
Here is the main Inference code and initial value:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
import csv
import cifar10
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

IMAGE_SIZES = 32
IMAGE_CHANELS = 3
NUM_CLASSES = 10
FIRST_CONV_NUM = 64
SECOND_CONV_NUM = 192
THIRD_CONV_NUM = 384
FOURTH_CONV_NUM = 256
FIFTH_CONV_NUM = 256
MAX_POOL_SIZE = 3
BATCH_SIZE = 100
FIRST_FC_UNIT_NUM = 4096
SECOND_FC_UNIT_NUM = 1000
DROP_OUT_PRO = 0.5
THIRD_FC_UNIT_NUM = NUM_CLASSES
TRAIN_EPOCH = 10
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN = 50000
NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL = 10000
NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY = 350.0
LEARNING_RATE_DECAY_FACTOR = 0.1
INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE = 0.01
DISPLAY_STEPS = 5

def leaky_relu(x, alpha=0.0):
  return tf.nn.relu(x) - alpha * tf.nn.relu(-x)

def activation(x,alpha=0.0):
    if alpha > 0:
        return leaky_relu(x,alpha)
    else:
        return tf.nn.relu(x)


def Alex_Weight(weight_name, weight_shape, weight_stddev, weight_type):
    Weight = tf.truncated_normal(shape=weight_shape, stddev=weight_stddev,type=weight_type)
    return tf.Variable(initial_value=Weight, trainable=True, name=weight_name)

def Alex_Bias(bias_name, bias_shape, bias_type, bias_init=0.1):
    initial = tf.constant(bias_init, shape=bias_shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial, trainable=True, dtype=bias_type,name=bias_name)


def Alex_AddActivationSummary(out):
    tf.summary.histogram('/activations',out)
    tf.summary.scalar('/sparsity',tf.nn.zero_fraction(out))

def Alex_Conv(conv_name, input, weight, bias, strides, alpha=0.1,padding="SAME", activation=activation, act_name="ReLU"):
    with tf.name_scope(conv_name):
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, weight, [1, strides, strides, 1], padding)
        pre_activation = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, bias)
    with tf.name_scope(act_name):
        conv = activation(pre_activation,alpha=alpha)
return conv

def Alex_Pool(conv, ksize, strides, pool_fuction=tf.nn.max_pool, padding="SAME"):
    return pool_fuction(conv, [1, ksize, ksize, 1], [1, strides,strides, 1], padding)

def Alex_Fully_Connect( input, weight, bias, activation=tf.nn.relu, act_name="ReLU"):
    with tf.name_scope("Wx_b"):
        y = tf.add(tf.matmul(input, weight), bias)
    with tf.name_scope(act_name):
        fc = activation(y, act_name)
    return fc

def Alex_Norm(norm_name, pool):
    with tf.name_scope(norm_name):
        norm = tf.nn.lrn(pool, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75,
                      name=norm_name)
    return norm

def Alex_Inference(images):
    with tf.name_scope("First_Conv"):
        W1 = Alex_Weight("Fist_Conv_Weight", [5, 5, IMAGE_CHANELS, FIRST_CONV_NUM], weight_stddev=0.01,
                        weight_type=tf.float32)
        bias1 = Alex_Bias("First_Conv_Bias", [FIRST_CONV_NUM], tf.float32,bias_init=0.0)
        first_conv = Alex_Conv("First_Conv", images, W1, bias1, strides=1, padding="SAME")
        Alex_AddActivationSummary(first_conv)

    with tf.name_scope('lrn1') as scope:
        lrn1 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(first_conv,
                                                  alpha=1e-4,
                                                  beta=0.75,
                                                  depth_radius=2,
                                                  bias=2.0)

    with tf.name_scope("First_Pool"):
        first_pool = Alex_Pool(lrn1, MAX_POOL_SIZE, strides=2, padding="VALID")


    with tf.name_scope("Second_Conv"):
        W2 = Alex_Weight("Second_Conv_Weight", [5, 5, FIRST_CONV_NUM, SECOND_CONV_NUM], weight_stddev=0.01,
                        weight_type=tf.float32)
        bias2 = Alex_Bias("Second_Conv_Bias", [SECOND_CONV_NUM], tf.float32,bias_init=1.0)
        second_conv = Alex_Conv("Second_Conv", first_pool, W2, bias2, strides=1, padding="SAME")
        Alex_AddActivationSummary(second_conv)

    with tf.name_scope('lrn2') as scope:
        lrn2 = tf.nn.local_response_normalization(second_conv,
                                                  alpha=1e-4,
                                                  beta=0.75,
                                                  depth_radius=2,
                                                  bias=2.0)

    with tf.name_scope("Second_Pool"):
        second_pool = Alex_Pool(lrn2, MAX_POOL_SIZE, strides=2, padding="VALID")

    with tf.name_scope("Third_Conv"):
        W3 = Alex_Weight("Third_Conv_Weight", [3, 3, SECOND_CONV_NUM, THIRD_CONV_NUM], weight_stddev=0.01,
                        weight_type=tf.float32)
        bias3 = Alex_Bias("Third_Conv_Bias", [THIRD_CONV_NUM], tf.float32,bias_init=0.0)
        third_conv = Alex_Conv("Third_Conv", second_pool, W3, bias3, strides=1, padding="SAME")
        Alex_AddActivationSummary(third_conv)

    with tf.name_scope("Fourth_Conv"):
        W4 = Alex_Weight("Fourth_Conv_Weight", [3, 3, THIRD_CONV_NUM, FOURTH_CONV_NUM], weight_stddev=0.01,
                        weight_type=tf.float32)
        bias4 = Alex_Bias("Fourth_Conv_Bias", [FOURTH_CONV_NUM], tf.float32,bias_init=1.0)
        fourth_conv = Alex_Conv("Fourth_Conv", third_conv, W4, bias4, strides=1, padding="SAME")
        Alex_AddActivationSummary(fourth_conv)

    with tf.name_scope("Fifth_Conv"):
        W5 = Alex_Weight("Fifth_Conv_Weight", [3, 3, FOURTH_CONV_NUM, FIFTH_CONV_NUM], weight_stddev=0.01,
                        weight_type=tf.float32)
        bias5 = Alex_Bias("Fifth_Conv_Bias", [FIFTH_CONV_NUM], tf.float32,bias_init=1.0)
        fifth_conv = Alex_Conv("Fifth_Conv", fourth_conv, W5, bias5, strides=1, padding="SAME")
        Alex_AddActivationSummary(fifth_conv)

    with tf.name_scope("Third_Pool"):
        third_pool = Alex_Pool(fifth_conv, MAX_POOL_SIZE, strides=2, padding="VALID")

    with tf.name_scope("Flatten"):
        flatten = tf.reshape(third_pool, [BATCH_SIZE, -1])
        flatten_dim = flatten.get_shape()[1].value

    with tf.name_scope("First_Fully_Connection"):
        W = Alex_Weight("Fist_FC_Weight", [flatten_dim, FIRST_FC_UNIT_NUM], weight_stddev=4e-2, weight_type=tf.float32)
        bias = Alex_Bias("First_FC_Bias", [FIRST_FC_UNIT_NUM], tf.float32, bias_init=1.0)
        fc1 = Alex_Fully_Connect(flatten, W, bias, activation=tf.nn.relu, act_name="ReLU")
        Alex_AddActivationSummary(fc1)

    with tf.name_scope("Drop_Out_1"):
        drop_out_1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, DROP_OUT_PRO)

    with tf.name_scope("Second_Fully_Connection"):
        W = Alex_Weight("Second_FC_Weight", [FIRST_FC_UNIT_NUM, SECOND_FC_UNIT_NUM], weight_stddev=4e-2,
                        weight_type=tf.float32)
        bias = Alex_Bias("Second_FC_Bias", [SECOND_FC_UNIT_NUM], tf.float32, bias_init=1.0)
        fc2 = Alex_Fully_Connect(drop_out_1, W, bias, activation=tf.nn.relu, act_name="ReLU")
        Alex_AddActivationSummary(fc2)

    with tf.name_scope("Drop_Out_2"):
        drop_out_2 = tf.nn.dropout(fc2, DROP_OUT_PRO)

    with tf.name_scope("Third_Fully_Connection"):
        W = Alex_Weight("Third_FC_Weight", [SECOND_FC_UNIT_NUM, THIRD_FC_UNIT_NUM], weight_stddev=1/SECOND_FC_UNIT_NUM,
                        weight_type=tf.float32)
        bias = Alex_Bias("Third_FC_Bias", [THIRD_FC_UNIT_NUM], tf.float32,bias_init=1.0)
        fc3 = Alex_Fully_Connect(drop_out_2, W, bias, activation=tf.nn.relu, act_name="ReLU")
        Alex_AddActivationSummary(fc3)

    return fc3
```

Comment: BTW: I consider the dying ReLU, so I changed the input with random, and get same output in each dimension.  And used Leaky-ReLU also.

Comment: I'd recommend commenting out all but your first layer to see if you can get anything that's not zero.  I do note that your calls to local_response_normalization/lrn have very low alpha values, given that the default is 1.

Comment: I checked output of every layer include dropout and fully-connection layer. And it seemed normal, except final layer(f3, according to the code). f3 is always zero after 10 or 20 iterates, and accuracy is 100%. It's so weird. the initial value of LRN is the same with the paper, and I tried the default value 1, got the same result. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I have solved this problem as follow:
1. Replace the CONV activation function with L-ReLU, as well as the fully-connection layer
2. Initial the learning rate with 0.001, and decay with 0.5 every 1000 training steps.
After 10000 iterations ( about 25 mins), I get 62%+ accuracy in testing-data, while 70%+ in training-data.
It's not a good result, maybe I train the net more times it would be better.